# Adding victory-native makes the tests hang

Tags: detox

For more details please see the following example: https://github.com/Osedea/react-native-victory-native-detox-bug

**Versions:**
Detox: 15.2.2
Victory-native: 34.0.0

Please see the logs below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7JNg.png)

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Can you please add some code and what error you are seeing? Are you seeing any output at all?

Comment: Please follow the documentation on how to debug what is causing this. It is most likely something in that project, in which case you should take with up with the team developing it. If not, open a new issue with Detox and provide all the information.

Comment: Any update with this issue? I face the same problem today :(